# Error al crear una clase usando una interface

Tags: angular, typescript, class, interface

tengo un problema intentando definir una clase que implementa una interfase que tiene objetos anidados.

Si bien la idea es asignarle valores que provienen de un formulario en este caso intenté incluso darle valores fijos pero el error es el mismo cada vez que intento crear un nuevo objeto de la clase Cliente.

```
const cliente = new Cliente (dataForm)
```

No alcanzo a darme cuenta donde esta el error. Desde ya les agradezco.

```
> NuevoClienteComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'calle' of undefined
    at new Cliente (cliente.ts:20)
    at NuevoClienteComponent.save (nuevo-cliente.component.ts:21)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NuevoClienteComponent.html:9)
    at handleEvent (core.js:36759)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:38377)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:38013)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:24335)
    at core.js:26203
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:29565)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)



export interface Cliente {
    id: string;
    grupo?: string;
    nombre: string;
    cuit: string;
    direccion: {calle: string, altura: string};
    localidad: string;
    codPostal: string;
    contactos?: {nombre: string; telefono: string; mail: string};
}

export class Cliente implements Cliente {

  constructor(cliente) {
    this.id = null;
    this.grupo ? this.grupo = cliente.grupo : this.grupo = null;
    this.nombre = cliente.nombre.value;
    this.cuit = cliente.cuit.value;
    this.direccion.calle = 'calle';
    this.direccion.altura = '';
    this.localidad = cliente.localidad.value;
    this.codPostal = cliente.codigoPostal.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No haz inicializado `direccion: {calle: string, altura: string};` por que proviene de una interfaz.

Tienes que inicializarlo primero para que puedas utilizarlo de esta manera:

```js
    export class Cliente implements Cliente {

    constructor(cliente) {
    // ... tu otro codigo en la clase
    //Debes inicializar el objeto de esta manera por que si no 
    // estas trabajando con un objeto nulo. 
    this.direccion = { calle: null, altura: null}
    this.direccion.calle = 'calle';
    this.direccion.altura = '';
    //... mas codigo
}
```

Recuerda que las interfaces solo son una muestra de como debe ser el código y no inicializan las variables. Al acceder de la manera `this.direccion.altura` supones que ya creaste un objeto `{}` y que luego le agregaste propiedades `{calle:string, altura: string}`. Si no lo haces así apuntas a un `null`.

Lo mismo te puede pasar con `contactos?: {nombre: string; telefono: string; mail: string};` Solo que en este caso es opcional y por eso no te lo pide el constructor. Si no lo inicializas no vas a encontrar propiedades por que no existen aun.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!